# How to send data using Input Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an interface to fill the fields, where you can add fields and delete them:

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group bg-light text-center pt-3 pb-3">
        <b><h3>Create Form</h3></b>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="HeadField">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Description Field"></textarea><br>
    </div>
    <h5>Fields:</h5><br>    
    <div class="border border-secondary rounded p-3" id="container">
        <div class="field">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                    <input class="form-control form-control-inline" placeholder="Head of field">
                </div>
                <select class="selectBox form-control col-md-6 ml-4" onchange="addElement(this);">
                    <option value='textarea'>Typefield1</option>
                    <option value='textarea'>Typefield2</option>
                    <option value='textarea'>Typefield3</option>
                    <option value='input'>Typefield4</option>
                    <option value='input'>Typefield5</option>
                </select>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs col-md-1 ml-3" value="X" onclick="removeField(this);"><br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='content'>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-check text-right">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" required/>Require<br>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-right mt-3">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="addField" onclick="addField(this);"><br><br>
</div>
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Close">
    </div>
</form>
```

I need to use the input model to send data to the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult EditForm(Model model)
                {
//fill model in BD using Linq or ather...do something
                }
```

What should the input model look like in my case? Not sure, like this is called model binding, but I'm new to asp net mvc.
addField:

```
function addField(btn) {
  var form = btn.closest("form");
  if (form) {
    var div = form.querySelector(".field");
    if (div) {
      var divCreated = document.createElement("div");
      divCreated.className = div.className;
      divCreated.innerHTML = div.innerHTML;
      document.getElementById('container').appendChild(divCreated);
    }
  }
}
```

And function addElement() adds element in div with id="content".

Comment: Can you post the content of your javascript function `addField`? Based on how you are serializing your data will determine the design of your model / viewmodel.

Comment: Posted function addField

Comment: Can you add your model code?

Comment: For Model Binding to work automatically your input elements must have "name" attribute corresponding to the model properties(exactly the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we don't know your model, this is one example how to do it using

> public class PersonModel {
>
> ```
>  public int PersonId { get; set; }
>
> public string Name { get; set; }
>
> public string Gender { get; set; }
>
> public string City { get; set; } }
> ```

And do the following in your VIEW

> @model Form_Post_MVC.Models.PersonModel
>   @{
>       Layout = null; }
>   Blockquote

> ```
> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
> <title>Index</title> </head> <body>
> @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
> {
>     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
>         <tr>
>             <th colspan="2" align="center">Person Details</th>
>         </tr>
>         <tr>
>             <td>PersonId: </td>
>             <td>
>                 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PersonId)
>             </td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr>
>             <td>Name: </td>
>             <td>
>                 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
>             </td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr>
>             <td>Gender: </td>
>             <td>
>                 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, new List<SelectListItem>
>                { new SelectListItem{Text="Male", Value="M"},
>                  new SelectListItem{Text="Female", Value="F"}}, "Please select")
>             </td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr>
>             <td>City: </td>
>             <td>
>                 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.City)
>             </td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr>
>             <td></td>
>             <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
>         </tr>
>     </table>
> } </body> </html>
> ```

Your HTML controls are matching the names in Model, and you are using the Post the controller must receive the data as expected

Answer (score 0):

Hi if I understood your question truly There are several ways for this I want to explain you one of the simplest way:
first of all your action method should look like code below

```
public ActionResult EditForm(Model model)
    {
       return View("ViewName", model);
    }
```

after that in view you should use model

```
@model Models.ViewModels.Model
```

next you can use Html helpers to generate your inputs for example

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "form-control", cols = "2" })
```